# How to graph differential equations on ti-83?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$f(t)=11(1-e^{-0.5t}),  \\g(t)=0.6t$$

How do I enter this into Ti-83 ?

They're asking to find the time after $t=0$ when the rate that pollution enters the lake equals the rate the pollution is removed.

The answer is the graph intersects at time $t= 18$

Comment: I think you have an issue with the exponent on the exponential term - shouldn't it be negative?

Comment: Yes thats right, accidentally got left out after editing

Comment: [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11+-+11%2FE%5E(t%2F2)+%3D(3*t)%2F5) (click on Approximate Form to see the actual numercal result - which you can solve for using the Lambert W Function). Also see plot. Also, I wonder if this is the issue on the TI-83 - https://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp%3FnSetId%3D93873?

Comment: This might also be helpful - https://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetId=71194

Comment: I'm not sure what i'm supposed to enter in the calculator but I entered as shown above but I'm just getting two straight lines that intersect at 0

Comment: Zero is one of the two intersection points, you need to make sure that you include a wider range to plot to find the second on in the plot.

Comment: But my graph isn't matching up with theirs, I enter in these two lines on my calc 11(1−e−0.5t), g(t)=0.6t I know I must be entering the wrong thing? I just get to two straight lines, while their graph shows one that is curved?

Comment: Don't you have to enter it as: 11*(1 - e^(-0.5*t))

Comment: omgosh I feel like such an idiot! Thank you so much! I changed the window to a wider range